# UIScrollView mysteriously changing frame and content size

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view in my app, initialized through storyboard, and I am attempting to change the frame. Everything seems to work, but if the frame and content size are accessed just a short time after they are set, but after my method returns, they are different! Here is the code:

```
CGFloat inputHeight = inputView.frame.size.height;
originalContentHeight = self.scrollableContentView.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollableContentView.frame.size.height-inputHeight);
[self.scrollableContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollableContentView.frame.origin.x, self.scrollableContentView.frame.origin.y, self.scrollableContentView.frame.size.width, self.scrollableContentView.frame.size.height-inputHeight)];
NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollableContentView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"%@", self.scrollableContentView);
```

The output of these logs are all as expected, that is:

```
<UIScrollView: 0x808de00; frame = (0 0; 320 81); ... >
```

However, if I set a breakpoint in another method, by the time that is called, logging the scrollView shows this:

```
<UIScrollView: 0x808de00; frame = (0 0; 320 416); ... >
```

Additionally, the content size changes as such:

```
(width=320, height=416)
```

to

```
(width=320, height=504)
```

Both of the values seem to be reverting automatically to the values they have when the view is first laid out. I have set breakpoints in the getter and setter of my scroll view, and cannot find any unexpected accesses, so I have concluded that the change must come internally. Is this a justifiable conclusion? What could be going wrong?

Comment: Could you have the autoresizing springs set to adjustable height?

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: This is because of auto layout. Either turn that off, or change the size of the scroll view by adjusting constraints rather than setting frames.

Comment: in which method you are doing this?

Comment: In a method after the tap of a UIBarButtonItem.

@rdelmar, would the storyboard's autolayout features really affect my view after it has been instantiated? This code works when I call it from an NSNotification invoked method (for the keyboard appearing).

Comment: If you change a frame when auto layout is on, the frame will revert to what the constraints define whenever the view does another layout. That can be caused by almost any user interaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using autolayout you should be changing the constraints, not setting the scrollview's frame.

See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771729/1367622). It has some links to examples of how to set constraints programmatically.

Also, in which method are you setting the `frame` and `contentSize`? Since you are using a storyboard, if it is in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` it would be better to move this code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Comment: I do indeed have the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (as per my question history). I will try this later today.

Comment: Constraints are the way to go. I actually found that the best way to do it was to add an outlet to the constraint in Interface Builder, and then edit the `constant` property.

Comment: @Jumhyn Yes, I also find that's an easy way to change a constraint if it already exists in a storyboard. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @StepSharp  which method should I set the scrollView's content and contentSize, if my scrollView in a custom view not a view controller without auto layout ? thanks.